# Remove Row on Button Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to use the button "subtract" to remove the row it's clicked in.

"add" button is working well.

Html:

```
<table id="mytable" width="250px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  style="text-align:center;>
   <thead>
   <tr class="product">
   <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Item</strong></th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Qty.</strong></th>
   <th style="text-align:center;"><strong>Remarks</strong></th>
   </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr name="product" class="product">
   <td width="100px"><input type="text" width="100px" name="product" id="product" /></td>
   <td width="5px"><input type="text" width="5px" size="1" maxlength="2" name="qty" id="qty" /></td>
   <td width="100px"><input type="text" width="100px" height="14px" name="remarks" id="remarks" /></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="+" /></td>
   <td><input type="submit" name="subtract" id="subtract" value="-" /></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
```

What I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last').clone(true).insertAfter('#mytable tbody>tr:last');
$('#mytable tbody>tr:last #product').val('');
    $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #qty').val('');
        $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #remarks').val('');
            $('#mytable tbody>tr:last #add').val('+');
return false;
    });
});
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: By the way if one of the solutions helped you solve the problem you should accept that solution. Just click the checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the same id more than one time on a page..
Thus if each row has a button to delete that row you probably want to use a class name for targeting the element.
Thus I suggest switching to classes like this:

```
<td><input type="submit" name="subtract" class="subtract" value="-" /></td>
```

then in JS

```
$("input.subtract").click(function() {
 $(this).closest("tr").remove();    
});
```

You also need to fix your add button since if you have more than one row you will have duplicate ID's

Comment: +1 for using classes instead of ID's. Another +1 for the handler. Someone else will have to do that other +1.

Comment: Is there a way it will not delete the row if there is only 1 row?

Comment: Or The row with the minus only appears after you have added one row?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#subtract").click(function(e){
    $(this).closest(".product").remove();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I'd also recommend using a class instead of an id for subtract and add since you'll have multiple copies in the dom and it's considered bad manners to have duplicate IDs.

Comment: It's not just bad manners, it's *illegal*. You can get arrested for that.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Matt's code, this would also work:

```
$("input.subtract").click(function() {
 $(this).parents("tr").remove();    
});
```

I don't know if one is better than the other, but I can confirm that this code works.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is a good idea.. Closest is equivalent to $(this).parents("tr").first().remove() I believe..
I think parents keeps traversing up and will find all parents with a tr tag so if you had a website with nested tables this might do something different altogether.. closest traverses up until a match and stops.

Comment: Ah, good call. That's probably a better option then. Hopefully we're not using too many tables! ;)